# Space in while printing but not viewing PDF

Tags: spacing, pdf, ieeetran, printing

I am trying to write in a IEEETran class of latex. I have a very strange problem.

The minimum stripped code is as follows -

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\def    \b      {\beta~}
\begin{document}
consumed, so the first $\b$ tokens $v_0$, then the next
\end{document}
```

Now when I generate a pdf using pdflatex, my PDF output looks like this - 
[image]

However, when I try to print this PDF, the output looks like this - 
[image]
I do not understand why there is a space between v and 0. 
I grabbed this image, using the "print preview" of the printer.
Just for complete information, I tried using HP LaserJet p4015 and HP Color LaserJet 4650 pcl3 printers.

UPDATE
The fonts that are 
[image]

Comment: Your definition of `\b` is wrong; why would you add a non breaking space after "beta"?

Comment: it is because, i need a space after beta. if I don't do it, the result is beta and tokens get mixed up.

Comment: I haven't observed this on my printer. However why `\def    \b      {\beta~}`, not `\def\b{\beta~}` (without spaces around)?

Comment: I tried this, but it is the same problem. :(

Comment: @Raj What about 
`\def\b{$\beta\quad$}`
and usage:
consumed, so the first \b tokens $v_0$, then the next
?

Comment: no the problem is the same. even I checked with the article class. it is the same. also i checked by putting the space with `\;` in math mode, but still the same.

Comment: actually, what made the difference is using `latex` to generate DVI and then from DVI -> PS -> PDF. but the reason why i cannot use `latex` is I am having extra code with `tikz` and some other things, which are currently working with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I also tried to print to a file, and it gives me the same problem. Also I tried printing the document with acrobat reader. But still it is the same.

Comment: I can't replicate it but your definition is wrong indeed. I would expect an error but I think mathmode is supressing it. Also use `ieeeconf` from your own conference author kit not the `conference` mode.

Comment: But I am seeing this problem even with article class. I download the pdf generated from the link you mention. It has the same problem, which I have specified. Maybe there is a problem with both printers I used? I have seen this problem for the first time. I have used it many times before.

Comment: If I replace the sentence without definition like this `consumed, so the first $\beta~$ tokens $v_0$, then the next`, still the same problem.

Comment: The `~` in the definition is just wrong, but unrelated to your actual problem which looks like a badly configured printer driver. Have you another machine you can print the pdf from, as a test?

Comment: what I did was I printed to a file `pdf` and I see the problem in newly generated pdf. So the problem becomes like this. I generate a PDF using pdflatex. I can see in pdf viewer, that there is no space between v and 0. But when I goto print preview, I find a space there. So if I print this to a PDF file, and I open the PDF file, I can visually see this space (without going to print preview) in the new PDF.

Comment: I found the problem with the PDF. It is the `evince viewer`. I am using version `3.6.0`. I printed the document using `acroread`. And now the problem is gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the PDF. It is the `evince viewer`. I am using version `3.6.0`. I printed the document using `acroread`. And now the problem is gone!